# Ionic + AngularJS customizar função com $location

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Bom dia pessoal,

Gostaria de saber como faço para deixar esse código abaixo mais performático.

Tenho duas funções que a única diferença entre elas é o $location.path

Como consigo transformar isso em uma função só com essas duas condições?

Segue o exemplo.

```
$scope.initLogin = function() {
        if ($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
            $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me", {
                params: {
                    access_token: $localStorage.accessToken,
                    fields: "name, email",
                    format: "json"
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
                $scope.loginData = result.data;
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Houve um erro na solicitação, tente novamente.");
            $location.path("/login");
        }
    };

    $scope.initRegister = function() {
        if ($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true) {
            $http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me", {
                params: {
                    access_token: $localStorage.accessToken,
                    fields: "name, email",
                    format: "json"
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
                $scope.registerData = result.data;
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Houve um erro na solicitação, tente novamente.");
            $location.path("/pre-register");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Não rola simplesmente passar o path por parâmetro?

Comment: Fala tpsilva, eu deixei retornando para uma rota só mesmo, depois de logado o usuário atualizará quando achar necessário as outras informações que eu necessito. Vlw